# How to have nginx use a default page for non-domains

Tags: nginx, web-server

Not really sure how to word the title. Say for example I only want my webserver accessible from domains and NOT the IP. How can I set a default page for when it's accessed via the IP directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a default server with some index page:

```
server {
   listen 80 default;
   server_name _;
   root /var/www/default/;
}
```